# Android SQLite - unable to access tables except sql_master table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

Here is my code

```
    String queryTenants = "select * from tenants";
       String queryProperties = "select * from properties";
       String queryLeases = "select * from leases";
       String queryPayments = "select * from payment_history ";
       String queryCredit = "select * from credit_standing";
       String queryMaster = "select * from sqlite_master";


       Cursor curT=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryTenants,null);
       Cursor curP=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryProperties,null);
       Cursor curL=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryLeases,null);
       Cursor curPa=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryPayments,null);
       Cursor curC=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryCredit,null);
       Cursor curM=myDataBase.rawQuery(queryMaster,null);

       curT.moveToFirst();
       curP.moveToFirst();
       curL.moveToFirst();
       curPa.moveToFirst();
       curC.moveToFirst();
       curM.moveToFirst();curso

       System.out.println("Tenanst" + curT.getCount());
       System.out.println("Properties" + curP.getCount());
       System.out.println("Leases" + curL.getCount());
       System.out.println("Payments"+curPa.getCount());
       System.out.println("Credit"+curC.getCount());
       System.out.println("Master" + curM.getCount());
```

Each cursor.count for each table returns 0, except the master table. Using SQLite broswer, I can clearly see that the other tables are populated with rows and colums, but I cannot reach them. Please help

Comment: Seeing how you added data to the tables would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure you opened the database before you tried to run your queries?